# Can't seem to get correct sum of previous numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, input, sum

So I was working on finishing up a section of my code that wanted it to print out the sum of the numbers that came before what the user put in but I can't get the right sum. For instance, if the user put in "4" then the sum should be 10 as 4+3+2+1 = 10 but when I input 4 I get 5. Could someone please explain to me what is going on, I'm pretty sure it's in my for loop as that's the only part giving me trouble but I'm not sure. Also the first bit of code is just there since we were suppose to restrict the user to inputs between 3 and 10 and print the corresponding number of symbols afterwords. I got those parts just fine thankfully but the error might still be there for all I know. Thanks again for anybody willing to help

```
 int count2 = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to use for Part B loops: ");
        count2 = keybd.nextInt();
        if (count2 > 10 || count2 < 3) {
            System.out.print("Error: number must be between 3 and 10, inclusive.\n");
        }
    } while (count2 > 10 || count2 < 3);

    int i = 1;
    System.out.print("Spring");
    while (i <= count2) {
          System.out.print("/\\");
          i++;
    } 
    System.out.println("Break");

    System.out.print("Sum of values 1 through " + count2 + " = ");

    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= count2; i++);
    {
        sum += i;
    } 
    System.out.print(sum);
```

Comment: Lose that semicolon following the `for` line; it acts as the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: I feel so silly but happy right now, guess this is why I still have a long way to go if I wanna be  better programmer. I must keep working. Also It works fine now, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is the semi-colon (;) after your for loop. What your code is doing as it is now is looping the i counter from 1 to count2, then you exit the for loop with (i = count2 + 1), after that the block of code { sum += i } executes and makes the sum = count2 + 1

So just remove the semi-colon and you're good to go